# Noises after installing new coilovers

Tags: suspension, struts

Replaced my struts with new Tein coilovers. I don't have a torque wrench but all bolts seem firm. Test drive after installation has a near constant thumping noise from the rear regardless of bumps in the road. I still need wheel alignment so only topped at 15mph. Cluncking after new coilovers appears prevalent but this sounds more like it's hitting something. Maybe the end links?

The dampers have 16 clicks. I adjusted it 5 down from hardest.

Driver side rear (before I tightened the 2 knuckle bolts):
[image]

Old vs new. I kept the same height.
[image]

Comment: Is the ‘thumping’ frequency related to the vehicle speed?

Comment: Did you tighten all the bolts after the vehicle weight was back on the wheels.

Comment: Can you add a photo of the new parts.

Comment: Which car do you have?

Comment: In the first photo it appears that the hardware attaching the strut to the spindle is loose, Was this photo before the you finished?

Comment: Did the ball joints on the linkage seem ok?

Answer (score 2):

USE A TORQUE WRENCH. Turns out the lug nuts on the wheels came loose.

Comment: Glad you said it, because I was going to. "It seems tight enough" rarely is. _Especially_ for suspension parts.

Comment: I erred on the side of loose because I didn't want to risk breaking a bolt but having a wheel falling off is even worse. Glad I didn't go past 20mph.